# Reference sign after method declaration c++

Tags: c++

In what case is it benificial to declare a method or function using const& instead of just using const? I know that using const is saying that this method does not modify the members of a class but what exactly happens when i add the reference sign after?

Example:

```
int myclass::getInteger() const& {
    return theInt;
}
```

Is this a so called reference quailifier by the way? And more importantly
what does the reference sign say about the method getInteger? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a [ref-qualified member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions). The lvalue-reference notation on the right makes this function callable only on lvalues of `myclass`, that is:

```
myclass c;
c.getInteger(); // OK
myclass{}.getInteger(); // Compile-time error
```

Comment: Thanks but what are the actual benifits of restricting a method so that it can only be called using lvalues of myclass? Is not redundant to use a ref qualified member function this situation?

Comment: @Bonbin it's an unusual requirement, but this tool is available if you end up with a design where calling a certain function on an rvalue is definitely a bug.

Comment: It is mostly used when you also declare an overload with rvalue reference qualification: `getInteger() &&`